# function-expression R problem when using curve()

Tags: r

When plot using curve() in R I give a function as an argument. 
E.g.

```
f=function(x) x^2
curve(f,2,3)
```

I get the curve plotted.

But I have to work with the derivative function D(), which you have to give an *expression* as argument and I can't get my curve plotted.

This is my code:

```
#To get the derivative
f1 = expression((x)^2)
d1=D(f1,"x")

#To plot the curve
f1=function(x) eval(f1,"x")
curve(f1,2,3)
```

And the error is:

```
Error in eval(f1, "x") : invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

How can I fixed? I've tried to plot directly the expression and no result. I can fix the problem if I were able to convert the function to expression, but no clue either.

Thanks in advance, Alberto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mistyped because you want to evaluate **d1** and **NOT f1**

```
#To get the derivative
f1 = expression((x)^2)
d1=D(f1,"x")

#To plot the curve
f=function(x) eval(f1)
curve(f,2,3)
```

The code above works for me.

[image: Plot]

Comment: Not really, my problem is that I want to plot **f1** but I is an expression. Whether changing f1 to a class "call" or "function" or other way. Your code works, but you get the derivative plotted nor **f1**

Comment: yes, I misunderstood you, it should be just f1=function(x) eval(f1) then, I will update my answer

if you look at documentation you can actualy see the problem, because you pass the "envir" argument which is not required and it isn't what you really meant to do

Comment: Dont worry! In that case you get another error, *'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'*.

Comment: I didin't encounter this error in my evaluation. The code in my answer works perfectly in my case. Please update your question with your current error and code you run.

Comment: I've added plot to my answer so you can know I'm surprised it doesn't work for you :D keep me updated! ;)

Comment: Alright alright, now I've gotten it, thank you so much!